# Get string to other class (flutter)

Tags: class, flutter, dart

I need to get the link variable in the "MovieDetail" class, to use it in "void _detailDialog" but when I press the share button the value is null. The link variable is found in the class "VideoView"

```
class MovieDetail extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MovieDetailState createState() => _MovieDetailState();
}

class _MovieDetailState extends State<MovieDetail> {
  final videoView = VideoView();
  final moviesProvider = MoviesProvider();
  final scrollController = ScrollController();
  GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldkey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  void _detailDialog(BuildContext context) {
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: new Text('Enviar a WebVideoCaster'),
            content: new Text('(Necesitas descargar la app)'),
            actions: <Widget>[
              new FlatButton(
                child: new Text("Enviar"),
                onPressed: () {
                  Share.share(Cast.all(context, link: videoView.link));
                },
              )
            ],
          );
        });
  }
}

class VideoView extends StatefulWidget {
  final String link;
  final bool progress;

  VideoView(this.link, {this.progress = true});

  @override
  _VideoViewState createState() => _VideoViewState();
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow, can you please paste the code here? Reading from screen  captures makes troubleshooting much more dificult.

Comment: I don't understand your problem since it not explained clearly. My guess is that you are trying to pass a variable from one screen to another or something else. Check this out: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/passing-data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just need to pass the link while you create an instance of VideoView in `_MovieDetailState` class.

```
final videoView = VideoView("your-link-goes-here");
```